# Define type in for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function:

```
public hideOtherQuestions() {
    const questionContainers = document.getElementsByClassName('question-container');

    let questionContainer: Element;
    for (let questionContainer in questionContainers) {
        if (!questionContainer.classList.contains('visible')) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('question-container')[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        }
    }
}
```

The `questionsContainer` is an HTMLCollection of Elements. In the `for loop` the `let questionContainer` is defined as `string`.

Because of that I get the error for the `if` statement that `.classList` does not exist on `string`

How do I change the type of the `let` in the for loop from `string` to `Element`?

Comment: Would casting work? I'm not terribly familiar with TS, but I have a general idea.

Comment: Oh yea, I suppose I have to cast the string to an Element. Haven't worked with typescript for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `of` instead of `in`.

- `in` refers to the `key` which is a string
- `of` refers to the `value` which is your object

So, by taking the following steps:

1. Wrap your collection in an `Array.from()`
2. Change your `for` from an `in` to an `of`

You should then get the results you were expecting

```
public hideOtherQuestions() {
    const questionContainers = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('question-container'));

    let questionContainer: Element;
    for (let questionContainer of questionContainers) {
        if (!questionContainer.classList.contains('visible')) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('question-container')[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you will want to set the val in the loop like so:

```
for (let key in questionContainers) {
  let questionContainer = questionContainers[key]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good tip! This does cause the problem that `HTMLCollectionOf` is not a array but I should be able to fix that.

Comment: You should be able to wrapp it in an `Array.from(myCollection)`

Answer (score 1):

The `in` keyword when used in a loop like that will extract the keys of the object you're iterating on, *not* the values. Keys of an object are strings, so Typescript is correct in pointing out that error.

Since it's an HTMLCollection, and not a proper array, you can't use a `for`/`of` loop either. So you'll be stuck with the old fashioned index loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < questionContainers.length; i++) {
    const questionContainer = questionContainers.item(i)
    if (!questionContainer.classList.contains('visible')) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('question-container')[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to use the `for`/`of` loop, you might be able to use the `Array.from` method to transform the collection to a real array:

```
for (let questionContainer of Array.from(questionContainers)) {
    if (!questionContainer.classList.contains('visible')) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('question-container')[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    }
}
```